# Помогите понять поведение Enum в Java

Tags: java, enum

Есть такой код:

```
public class Solution {
public static enum E1 {A, B, C, Y}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution.switchTest(E1.C);

    /* output
    it's E1.C
             */
}

public static void switchTest(Enum obj) {
    switch (obj.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
        case "E1":
            System.out.println("it's " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + obj);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("undefined");
    }
}
```

Результатом его выполнения будет, как вы могли догадаться, "it's E1.C".

Так вот, когда мы доходим в дебагере до "switch (obj.getClass().getSimpleName())", то в результате получаем "C".

Так каким боком мы проходим case, и мало того, получаем в консоль "E1.C" ?!

Update 1:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: в дебаге у вас отображается toString для obj,  а obj это E1.C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам написали уже в комментарии, это выводится результат `toString` для `obj`.
В отладочном режиме есть крутая фича - Evaluate Expression, указал на картинке куда тыкать. Выделяете нужное вам выражение, затем нажимаете туда, оно у вас появляется в открывшемся окошке, нажимаете Evaluate - получаете результат его вычисления в текущем месте программы, в котором вы остановились. Так же там можно писать свои выражения, используя все видимые в текущем месте компоненты программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

То что вы описали, очень странно. Так как енум в `java` это обычный класс, а `A,B,C,Y` - это объекты данного класса. Соответственно, класса с именем `С` у вас нет и быть не может.